# How can I use nginx-proxy to reverse-proxy a website that is not running in a container?

Tags: docker, nginx, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I understand how to use nginx-proxy so that I can reverse proxy to services running in multiple docker containers.  However I have several websites on my network that are *not* running in containers that I also want to reverse proxy.  In the official nginx-proxy support forum one user said you can accomplish this:

> You can create an "additional.conf" for nginx. There is documentation
>   on the main README page.
>
> In this additional.conf, you would create a server configuration for
>   the name and map it to the IP address of your destination.
>
> You'll need to ensure that the destination IP is accessible from
>   within the container. Looking at your options for a Docker network
>   type (host vs bridge, etc.) might help.

However I’m unable to find anything discussing how to create a new .conf file where I would perform the ip mapping.  Is this user correct?  Any examples would be appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, your nginx instance *is* running in a docker container, but you want it to proxy for web applications that are *not* running in docker containers?  Just making sure I'm clear.

Comment: Correct.  I’d like all of the proxying to be done in one place.

Comment: In fact, I don’t know how it would be possible to use more than one instance of nginx if I want to use only 80,443 from the Internet.